# How to upgrade back to xorg 1.13 after downgrade to 1.12 in ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, xorg, fglrx, downgrade

I had to downgrade Xorg from 1.13 to 1.12 in order to use the fglrx-legacy but it (fglrx-legacy) didn't work for me neither fglrx. So, is it possible to upgrade Xorg back to 1.13? and how?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! How did you downgrade to 1.12 in the first place? Please *edit* your question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Install Synaptic package manager, find xorg-server package with ppa version 1.12, then from menu choose 'force version', and select 'ubuntu-updates'. After all, you'll loose all the system, but that's repairable: in terminal, type

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Have fun! :-)

Comment: You mean `quantal-updates` I guess? And this will only work if he indeed used a PPA (which is not necessarily the case). Also, the package `ubuntu-desktop` is probably already installed and this command won't do anything in such a case...

Comment: On my system, forcing standard xorg-server package in Synaptic deletes all video drivers also. 'ubuntu-desktop' package restored all of them. That is because xorg-server has lot of dependants.